# Interesting example of proof by contrapositive?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

By interesting I mean examples that go beyond the simple examples found in introductory textbooks about proofs. Also, are there any famous theorems that use proof by contrapositive, or at least variants of proofs of such theorems which use contrapositive?

Comment: Many  so-called ‘proofs by contradiction’ are actually proofs by contrapositive

Answer (score 1):

Example

Let $f $ be a function from R to R.

If for each sequence $(x_n) $ which converges to $a $, the sequence $(f(x_n)) $  converges to $L $

then $(\implies) $

$$\lim_{x\to a}f (x)=L $$